# is clearing the buffer by assigning char * buffer to '\n' while getting user input inside a loop in c wrong?

Tags: c, fgets, input-buffer

I tried to solve the problem* I face when I want to get user input inside a loop.
edit *: problem is this -> clearing buffer to read next input.

is this error-prone?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
      int main(){
        char buffer[10];
        while(1){
          fgets(buffer,10,stdin);
          // use buffer for whatever i need... THEN!
          *buffer = '\n';
        }
    }
```

Edit: This is the code i faced the error. without assignment to '\n' i got wrong loop coun and inputs. deleted those lines there is nothing wrong :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
        int numbers[100];
        int quant;
        char buffer[10];
        printf("how many numbers do i need to ask? MAX = 99\n");
        fgets(buffer,10,stdin);
        quant = atoi(buffer);
        *buffer = '\n';
        printf("%d times enter numbers! MAX 9 digit long !\n",quant);
        for(int i=0;i<quant;i++){
                printf("%d. number: ",i);
                fgets(buffer,10,stdin);
                numbers[i] = atoi(buffer);
                *buffer = '\n';

        }

        printf("Numbers: \n");
        for(int i=0;i<quant;i++){
                printf("%d ",numbers[i]);
        }
```

edit2: error was based on the memory overflow and how fgets handles inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int ch;
        char buffer[10];

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){

                fgets(buffer,10,stdin);
                printf("%s -- %d. time\n",buffer,i+1);
                //while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
                *buffer= '\n';
        }
        return 0;
}
```

If I enter more than 9 digits as an input (which i did accidentally), jumps to the next loop. If I clear buffer with while loop then nothing wrong happens.
*buffer = '\n' useless, meaningles...

Comment: There is none wrong in the statement `*buffer = '\n';` alone, but what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: `*buffer  = '\n';`  ------> `buffer[9] = '\0';`

Comment: most likely you want to set it to `'\0'` if you want to "clear" the buffer

Comment: `*buffer = '\n';` does not "clear a buffer", it overwrites the first element.

Comment: i think it is a pointer. making pointer null or something like that?

Comment: `buffer` is a `char [10]`, not a pointer.

Comment: note that it does not overwrite the 10 chars of your buffer ; it just replaces the first element with a newline. if you really want to 'clear' it all, you need to write something to all 10 elements, for example `buffer[i]='\n'` for i=0..9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not "error-prone", but it is pointless.

There is very rarely any point in "clearing" a buffer, and it's never well-defined what "clearing" means.

Why do you feel the buffer needs to be cleared, when it's going to be overwritten by `fget()`, regardless of its contents? If the behavior is confusing, you should make sure `fgets()` succeeds before relying on the result.

Comment: it doesnt overwritten when i try to get inputs inside a loop.

Comment: @zuxi Right after the overwrite comes the call to `fgets()`, which doesn't care at all what is already in the buffer, but simply overwrites it with as much input as possible. So yes, it is.

Comment: It is not overwritten and it caused loop to jump next one if input is larger than buffer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the context the code deals with strings. So an empty (cleared) buffer is a buffer that contains an empty string.

So you should write

```
buffer[0] = '\0';
```

If you mean an empty string read by the function `fgets` then in this case an empty (cleared) buffer can look like

```
buffer[0] = '\n';
buffer[1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding what you use the buffer for and why you want to clear it in the first place:

How to clear a buffer:

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
```

Comment: note that you can replace `sizeof(buffer)` by `sizeof(char)*10` in this case.

Comment: @FlorianCastellane that's a bad idea, firstly you reproduce a "magic number" and secondly `sizeof(char)` is `1` *by definition*. I suggest `sizeof buffer` as parentheses are only needed for a type.

Comment: @FlorianCastellane: That's bad practice. You use a magic number, add redundancy and `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`. THe original is fine.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Not to forget the redundancy: what if `buffer` changes?

Comment: I personally always use sizeof with parentheses, so my eyes don't need to recognise two different patterns. Just my preference. And using `10` is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf good point: `sizeof buffer` is transparent.